# Rooting EPad MX1014

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, angry-birds

I have a [E-Pad MX1014](http://www.grabargains.com/Epad-MX1014/MX1014-addtionalinfo.html) (chinese tabcrap) and I am trying to access the system apps so I can uninstall *Angry Birds* off it.

The Angry Birds it runs is an extremely old version and for some reason it will not update it. I have tried installing different versions like *Angry Birds Star Wars* or *Seasons* and trying to just install the *Angry Birds* app over the top with no luck...

I cannot access the device via `USB` because the "adapter" to change from the current plug to USB has died. I have been using SnapPea via the wifi to put apps and such on it.

I have tried `Z4Root`, `GingerBreak` and tried getting `BusyBox` and `SuperSu` onto it, but I keep getting cannot install errors and missing binary errors... Z4Root when I hit root (either temp or perm) will say `it's rooting it` then go to home screen and nothing else happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The tablet runs `Android 2.3`.

P.S. if I had the money I would buy a better tablet, but this is just for my son and he is an angry bird fanatic....